# Prevent cache in every Dojo xhr request on page

Tags: javascript, caching, dojo, xmlhttprequest, intercept

I'm able to intercept Dojo 1.6.1 xhr requests using *IO Pipeline Topics* as described here:

[Dojo - intercepting XHR calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781018/dojo-intercepting-xhr-calls)

I would like to add a time parameter to the URL (f.e. `&time=12345`) to prevent cache in certain (or all) xhr GET requests originating from `dojox.data.JsonRestStore` (details of what I'm trying to achieve are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519695/how-to-disable-cache-in-extlib-rest-control-which-uses-dojox-data-jsonreststore)). My code looks like this:

```
dojo.subscribe("/dojo/io/send", function(deferred) {

    if (deferred.ioArgs.url.indexOf("restService1") > -1) {
        deferred.cancel();
        deferred.ioArgs.url += '&time=12345' // test value at this point
        dojo.xhrGet(deferrred.ioArgs);
    }
});
```

Basically I'm trying to cancel the request, add a string to URL and then make the request with the modified URL.

This does not work at all: the request with modified URL does not end up to the server and I'm getting a lot of these errors to browser console:

[image: Chrome errors]

The errors occur in line 14 of dojo.js. The Chrome tab crashes eventually after these errors.

I also tried just modifying `deferred.ioArgs.url` and doing nothing else but that has no effect.

Comment: Can you not modify your request URL prior to sending the xhr request? Or in the cases where you want to prevent caching you can add preventCache: true to your dojo xhr request.

Comment: @pjdanfor Not without modifying Dojo source. Sorry I should have included this info in my question (see also below my comment for the answer). The question has been modified now.

Comment: You could subclass JsonRestStore and implement the method that issues the xhr request to include your additional functionality.

Comment: Good idea. But the Dojo/JavaScript code is generated by Domino server which makes it difficult or impossible to do things like that in this case.

Comment: That's unfortunate - canceling requests every time you have to prevent cache for a particular endpoint and resending it really isn't a good solution though.

Comment: @pjdanfor Right. We are at the point where we may have to discard the fully developed Dojo DataGrid based solution and build it based on something else (the problems did not occur before customer tested in their environment). Actually I was hoping I could just add this one param to the URL on the fly without cancelling anything.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you can't subclass a dojo class. You don't have any control over what javascript is used/generated?

Comment: @pjdanfor Basically so. In this implementation I'm using design controls that generate all Dojo stuff. The idea is of course to make things as easy for me as possible :-). Now that I checked, It's loading these and lots of other stuff: ItemFileReadStore.js, XPagesRestStore.js, JsonRestStore.js, JsonRest.js, Rest.js, ServiceStore.js. I can't even be sure which one sends the requests. I will have to think if there would be a way to subclass the requester in this case (which I would have to find and then find the code from it...). Right now it does not sound possible to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer comes once again from **Sven Hasselbach**:

```
/**
 * Cache Prevention for Dojo xhr requests
 *
 * Adds no-cache header and enables dojo's preventCache feature
 * for every dojo xhr call. This prevents the caching of partial
 * refreshs.
 *
 * @author Sven Hasselbach
 * @version 0.3
 *
 **/
dojo.addOnLoad(
    function(){
        if( !dojo._xhr )
        dojo._xhr = dojo.xhr;

        dojo.xhr = function(){        
            try{
                var args = arguments[1];   
                args["preventCache"] = true;
                args["headers"] = { "cache-control": "no-cache" };
                arguments[1] = args;
          }catch(e){}

          dojo._xhr( arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2] );
        }
    }
)
```

http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=cache-prevention-for-dojo-xhr-requests

Tried it out and it does exactly what I was looking for by adding `&dojo.preventCache=1359366392301` parameter to the xhr URLs. And it seems to add a *cache-control* header too.

Answer (score 2):

Both `dojo/io/script` and `dojo/xhr` have a `preventCache` parameter that does exactly what you are trying to do.  So instead of trying to intercept, can you just add `preventCache: true` to the request arguments?

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojo/io/script.html#dojo-io-script

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojo/xhrGet.html#dojo-xhrget

Comment: These requests are made by dojox.data.JsonRestStore (as described in my linked post) so I guess I'd have to change the Dojo source code to modify the original xhrGet request. I wouldn't like to go there. I will add this info to my question.