# Dynamically pass all paramaters in grails remoteLink

Tags: grails, parameters

How to pass all parameters with a grails remoteLink. I've tried a lot of thing but did not manage to get it working....

```
<g:remoteLink action="show" update='resultset' method="post" params="[params:params]">Testing</g:remoteLink>


<g:remoteLink action="show" update='resultset' method="post" params="[params:${params}]">Testing</g:remoteLink>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<g:remoteLink action="show" update='resultset' method="post" params="${params}">Testing</g:remoteLink>
```

Params is a Map already, so you don't need to do anything special.

Comment: The parameters get set. But the link doesn't work correctly... It reloads the whole page instead of only the div specified in the update propertie. Actually the ajax doesn't get called only the link is followed.

Comment: If I enter a param manual like: params="offset:12" it works!
Another thing if I remove method="post" I get an error in console: [10:06:58.806] SyntaxError: missing ] after element list @

Comment: what you get in html as a result? btw, does it really use `offset:12`? it's not a map, just a string.

Comment: I have some dojo.preventCache in my params maybe this is causing ajax to fail!

Comment: Another thing: How can I add another parameter in addition?

Comment: You can use `params="${params + [newparam: avalue]}"`

Answer (score 0):

`Dojo.preventCache` was messing up with my AJAX. When I removed it started working.
[Prevent cache in every Dojo xhr request on page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530284/prevent-cache-in-every-dojo-xhr-request-on-page)